# How can I prevent next.js from sending source mappings to the browser?

Tags: next.js

Next.js is sending my source files to the browser so they are easily accessible to anyone via devtools in the browser. This is a problem because those files contain `getServerSideProps` functions with my api keys.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

You have to add `productionBrowserSourceMaps: false` in `next.config.js` then run `npm run build`, and them `npm run start`, the source maps will be gone in production. They will still appear if you run `npm run dev`, but they won't in production.

Hope I helped someone.